# Optional resources within a SimPy

Tags: python, simpy

I'm using Simpy for discrete event simulation and am having problems with what I can best describe as optional resources. The context is that I am simulating missions which will be undertaken and will demand some assets (resources) to undertake that mission. Unlike most SimPy implementations, the mission needs to start at the allocated time or else fails and may accept lesser resources to enable the mission to start.

For example a mission requires four vehicles at time = t. At time t only three vehicles are available, so the mission commences with three vehicles but has a lesser outcome. If only two or less vehicles are available, the mission would not go ahead and would be considered as failed.

Sorry for the lack of code in this example, I'm struggling to get my head around it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used containers to track resources, but take a look and let me know if this is what you want

```
"""
Demos checking the availability of resources befor taking resouces

Each agent has a first choice and second choice for seizing resources
if neither choice is avalale will not wait and skip getting resources

programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random

def eval(choice, containers):
    """
    steps through each requirement and checks if there is enough resouces is available

    returns True if there is enough, else returns False
    """
    for k,v in choice.items():
        if containers[k].level < v:
            # not enough
            return False
    return True

def mission(env, id, firstChoice, secondChoice, startDelay, missingTime, containers):
    """
    Sims agent checking if first or second choice of resouces is available
    If so, will seize the resources, hold for a time, and then release the resouces
    """

    choice = None   # which choice to use

    # wait for mission start
    yield env.timeout(startDelay)

    print()
    print(f'{env.now} agent {id} is starting a mission')
    x = [(k, v.level) for k, v in containers.items()]
    print(f'available: {x}')
    print(f'first choice {firstChoice}')
    print(f'second choice {secondChoice}')

    # evaluate the choices and see if either will work
    if eval(firstChoice, containers):
        choice = firstChoice
        print(f'{env.now} agent {id} is going with first Choice')
    else:
        if eval(secondChoice,containers):
            choice = secondChoice
            print(f'{env.now} agent {id} is going with second Choice')
        else:
             print(f'{env.now} agent {id} is abort because not enough resources')

    if choice is not None:
        # found a choice that works
        # seize the resouces, we checked that they are availale, so there should not be any queue time
        for k,v in choice.items():
            containers[k].get(v)
        
        yield env.timeout(missingTime)

        # return resouces
        for k,v in choice.items():
            containers[k].put(v)

        print(f'{env.now} agent {id} has finished the mission ')

def build_choice():
    """
    quick helper to generate random first and second choice requirements
    (may not use all three resouces)

    returns a dictionary of the requirements where key=type, value=how much
    """
    choice = {}
    while len(choice) == 0:
        for k in ['A','B','C']:
            v = random.randint(0,3)
            if v > 0:
                choice[k] = v
    return choice


def gen_missions(env, containers):
    """
    Generate a series of agents to seize the resources
    """

    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1 # id generator
        firstChoice = build_choice()
        secondChoice = build_choice()

        env.process(mission(env,i,firstChoice,secondChoice,random.randint(1,4),random.randint(2,8),containers))

        # put some time between agents
        yield env.timeout(1)

env = simpy.Environment()

# load the resouces
containers = {}
containers['A'] = simpy.Container(env, init=10, capacity=10)
containers['B'] = simpy.Container(env, init=10, capacity=10)
containers['C'] = simpy.Container(env, init=10, capacity=10)

# start generating agents
env.process(gen_missions(env,containers))

env.run(100)
```